# Подскажите, откуда взялся несуществующий margin по бокам?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.

Я немного в ступор впал, уже пол часа не могу понять откуда по бокам взялось 25px.

В коде его нет, в родительском элементе body (там padding 0 margin 0 width 100%).

Подскажите, откуда он может взяться и как его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется это нормально,у меня точно такая же схема на всех сайтах,можете создать чистый хтмл,и проверить,там будет тоже самое(на всякий случай проверте ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого элемента указаны свойства `margin-left` и `margin-right` со значением `auto`.

При таком раскладе элементу с обоих сторон устанавливается одинаковый отступ для заполнения всего оставшегося пространства по бокам, выравнивая таким образом элемент по центру.

Казалось бы, стоит свойство `width: 100%`, но также стоит свойство `max-width`, у которого бо́льший приоритет да ещё и `!important` в придачу.

Comment: Это задано на класс контейнера,а у него до самого бордера.

Comment: @Анатолий Шевелев, точно, вы правы, убираю `max-width` и `margin` сразу пропадает. Наверное это чисто визуальный блок для таких случаев

Comment: Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Это норма,я только что создал абсолютно пустой html файл,вот он:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня наверное меньше экран из-за этого и меньше сами параметры.

Comment: К чему этот скрин? Ты показываешь, что в твоём боди нет маргинов, почему тогда ты считаешь, что это ответ на вопрос?

Comment: В боди есть маргин 8,присмотритесь

Comment: В вашем случае это стандартное поведение браузера, нужно использовать `reset.css`

Comment: Спасибо,сразу на 2 вопроса ответили :))
Я теперь смогу наконец убрать маргин со своего сайта

Comment: Да пожалуйста )